# Can I change headings when printing values in a while?

Tags: jsp, while-loop, html-heading

I'm working on a social networking site and I want to print the 5 most popular people I follow.The result set is returning 5 most popular people I follow from database. I want the first one to be printed in an h1 heading, the second one in h2 and so on etc. My question is if there is any way to change the heading during the iteration without printing each result in if clauses.

**Bellow is my code**

```
<% ResultSet rs1 = dao.returnTop5(email); 
int i = 1; 
while (rs1.next()){ 
  String username1 = rs1.getString("username"); 
  String profilephoto = rs1.getString("profilephoto"); 
  String followers = rs1.getString("followers"); %> 
  <img src="<%= profilephoto %>" class="first" title="<%= username1 %>">
  <b><big>&nbsp <%= username1 %></a>
      <h2 class="color">#<%= i %> (<%= followers %> Followers)</h2>
  </big></b> <br> <% i++; 
 } %>
```

Comment: yes, but provide some code and details what you actually want? what you have tried?

Comment: <%

ResultSet rs1 = dao.returnTop5(email);

int i = 1;

while (rs1.next()){
 String username1 = rs1.getString("username");
 String profilephoto = rs1.getString("profilephoto"); 
 String followers = rs1.getString("followers");
%>
  <img src="<%= profilephoto %>" class="first" title="<%= username1 %>"><b><big>&nbsp <%= username1 %></a><h2 class="color">#<%= i %> (<%= followers %> Followers)</h2></big></b>
  <br>
<% 
 i++;
}
%>

Comment: there is only one loop do you mean in first iteration and 2nd iteration or first loop and 2nd loop?

Comment: In first iteration I want the h1 heading and in second iteration the h2 heading. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: check this answer out do you want something like this? other wise you can also edit your question to make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know what exactly do you want in heading but i hope this will help you out to write your program

```
<% ResultSet rs1 = dao.returnTop5(email); 
int i = 1; 
while (rs1.next()){ 
  String username1 = rs1.getString("username"); 
  String profilephoto = rs1.getString("profilephoto"); 
  String followers = rs1.getString("followers"); 
   %>
      <h<%=i%>><%= username1 %></h<%=i%>>
 <%
  i++; 
 } %>
```

bellow is the general program for you you can copy it and paste to the any jsp file to test bellow program

```
    <%
    for (int a=1; a<=5; a++){
     %>
        <h<%=a%>>Hello World!</h<%=a%>>
    <%
    }        
    %>
```

Comment: I'm working on a social networking site and I want to print the 5 most popular people I follow. But I want the first one to be printed in an h1 heading, the second one in an h2 etc. My question is if there is any way to change the heading during the iteration without printing each result in if clauses as in the code above.

Comment: i have updated answer without if condition and have added some code to help you understand i hope this will help.

Comment: try to edit your question if there is something missing eg: code or there is any requirement that you have not written